# Correct syntax and encoding for an API POST file upload using HTTR

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to upload a file with other data into an API. I can all the data in except for when I try to upload a file as part of the `POST` request in `httr`. With it being a live api I can't give a fully reproducible example but here is an example of a working request in httr:

```
library(httr)

post_result_ls <- POST(
   url   = "https://api.example.co/applications",
   body  = list(
     employer     = "12321lkjljlkj2130897",
     name         = "Jane Smith",
     email        = "jane.smith@email.com",
     job          = "098123lkj098sdlkjklj",
     stage        = "inbound"
   ),
   add_headers("x-access-token" =  "lkajsdlkj987987alsklksajdslk"),
   verbose = TRUE,
   encode = "json"
 )
```

I'm trying to add a file upload with `file_upload` like so:

```
post_result_ls <- POST(
  url   = "https://api.example.co/applications",
  body  = list(
    cv           = upload_file("testing/test_file.docx", type = "application/msword"),
    employer     = "12321lkjljlkj2130897",
    name         = "Jane Smith",
    email        = "jane.smith@email.com",
    job          = "098123lkj098sdlkjklj",
    stage        = "inbound"
  ),
  add_headers("x-access-token" =  "lkajsdlkj987987alsklksajdslk"),
  verbose = TRUE,
  encode = "json"
)
```

... an error is returned:

`Error: No method asJSON S3 class: form_file`

I have a working `curl` example for which the body looks like:

```
  --data-raw '{"cv":{"data":"/+//v///wAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAP7////+////+////HAAAAB0AAAAeAAAA/v/////v///BAP7/AwoAAP/////wIAaAAAAAcARABlAGYAYQB1AGwAdA",
  "filename":"test-new.doc","type":"application/msword"},"name":"John Smith","email":"smith@smith.com","phone":"123456","employer":"aaa444bbbb","source":"board","job":"5faaad78aaf21564dc1d2233"}' \
  --compressed
```

I think there are 2 issues:

1. The file upload (cv) is raw - looks like I need to specify that in `httr` just for the upload part.
2. There's a level of indentation for the cv file upload and its properties such as `filename` and I can't find how to do that.

Would be great if someone could help with the translation of the file upload `curl` to `httr` please. I've looked through a lot of documentation and previous posts, but can't find anything close to an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you also give https://curlconverter.com/r/ a whirl?

Comment: Thank you - I did and it provided some clues. I solved the issue and will post the answer.